# Shortest syntax for type tag lambda dispatch in C++ 17

Tags: lambda, c++17, tag-dispatching

I am restrained to use C++17 and I want to pass a type to a lambda by passing in a type tag, which I can in the following way in C++ 20 and C++17.

```
template<typename T>
struct Type
{
    using type = T;
};

auto lambda20 = []<typename T>(Type<T>){
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int>);
};
auto lambda17 = [](auto tag){
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename decltype(tag)::type, int>);
};

void test()
{
    lambda20(Type<int>{});
    lambda17(Type<int>{});
}
```

Is there a shorter syntax than the typename decltype(tag)::type I can use to extract the type from the type tag in C++ 17?

Comment: Why not just `auto lambda = [](Type<int>){ /* no assert needed anymore */ }`?

Comment: Because there are many cases which I don't want to write out, I want to instantiate other types using T.

Comment: It would help if you would give a more concrete example of how you want to use it.

Comment: Perhaps `template <typename T> using Type = T*;` Then you could use `decltype(*tag)`